# React router 4 history push component re render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, redux-saga

With `redux-saga` and `react router 4`. I am trying to implement a flow for user registration. I am focusing on the part where user is presented a registration screen on `/user/register` route.

**GOAL**

Goal is to update the status of user registration on this same screen as an `Alert` depending upon either the user created successfully or there already exists a user. I am using `redux-saga` and using `history.push` from saga to update the view.

**PROBLEM**

The alert is shown but only after I reload the `/user/register` page.

I am passing state to `history.push` from my saga and then in my component based on that state which I extract from `this.props.location.state` I prepare the content for alert.

**Register Component**

```
// Form submission handler
handleUserRegistration = user => {
   this.props.registerUser(user, this.props.history);
}

// Prepring the alert content
getAlertUI = signupState =>  {
   if (signupState.signupSuccess) {
       return <UncontrolledAlert color='success'>{'Verification email sent. Please verify your account.'}</UncontrolledAlert>
   }else {
       return <UncontrolledAlert color='danger'>{signupState.error.message}</UncontrolledAlert>
   }
}

render () {
  let alertContent = null;

  const signupResponse = this.props.location.state;
  if (signupResponse) {
   if (signupResponse.error) {
     alertContent = this.getAlertUI({signupSuccess: false, error: signupResponse.error});
   }else {
     if (signupResponse.verificationEmailSent) {
       alertContent = this.getAlertUI({signupSuccess: true})
     }
   }
  }

  return (
   <div> {alertContent} </div>
   // My form component goes here.
  )
}
```

While is my `saga`. I am using `history.push` with the necessary information.

**saga.js**

```
const registerWithEmailPasswordAsync = async (userData) =>

    await axios.post(apiUrls.SINGUP_USER, userData )
                    .then(response => {
                        return {
                            isError: false,
                            data: response.data,
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        return {
                            isError: true,
                            errorDetails: {
                                status: error.response ? error.response.status : null,
                                message: error.response ? error.response.data : null,
                            }
                        }
                    })

function* registerUser({ payload }) {
    const { history } = payload;
    try {
        const registerUser = yield call(registerWithEmailPasswordAsync, payload.user);
        if (!registerUser.isError) {
            history.push('/user/register', {verificationEmailSent: true});
        } else {
            if (registerUser.errorDetails) {
                history.push('/user/register', {error: registerUser.errorDetails} );
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('register error : ', error)
    }
}
```

I am pretty new to this, Please share if this is the better approach or not? And if it is why isn't it updating my view. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Don't use `history.push` just to update state**
   The only reason I could see you using `history.push` from within the saga is for sending the user to a dashboard/verification page after a successful sign up. There is no reason to use `history.push` just to pass some state to the component dynamically. Update your redux state by dispatching an action, not using `history.push`
2. **You don't necessarily have to update state to notify the user of a sign-up error**
   You asked if your general approach was the best. Personally, I don't think it is. I wouldn't work that hard. Just use something like [react-toastify](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction/). You can then just place a `ToastContainer` in your `App` component, then call `toastify(successMessage/error)`